# Spring Beans not being Lazy Loaded with DWR in Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dwr

Lazy loading of beans in my Spring MVC application is not working due to the DWR configuration I have in my web.xml file.  If I comment out the DWR configuration, the lazy loading works. I am seeing the beans ProgressWorker1 and ProgressWorker2 getting constructed during the startup of the application (I have a temporary println in the constructor of each bean).  These beans extend a ProgressWorker abstract class.  Below is my configuration and code.

Is DWR causing the issue or could multiple Servlet tags cause lazy loading of beans to not work?

web.xml (snippet)

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>tester</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dwr</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrSpringServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>activeReverseAjaxEnabled</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>maxWaitAfterWrite</param-name>
          <param-value>-1</param-value>
      </init-param>

      <init-param>
        <param-name>org.directwebremoting.extend.ServerLoadMonitor</param-name>
        <param-value>org.directwebremoting.impl.PollingServerLoadMonitor</param-value>
      </init-param>

      <init-param>
          <param-name>disconnectedTime</param-name>
          <param-value>1000</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dwr</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>tester</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

applicationContext.xml (snippet)

```
<bean id="progresssWorker" abstract="true" class="com.tester.progress.ProgressWorkerAbstract">
    <property name="testSystem" ref="testSystem"/>
    <property name="testService" ref="testSystemService"/>
    <property name="progressDao" ref="progressDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="progressWorker1" lazy-init="true" class="com.tester.progress.ProgressWorker1" parent="progresssWorker" />
<bean id="progressWorker2" lazy-init="true" class="com.tester.progress.ProgressWorker2" parent="progresssWorker" />

<bean id="progressWorkerFactory" class="com.tester.progress.ProgressWorkerFactoryImpl" />
```

ProgressWorkerFactoryImpl class

```
public class ProgressWorkerFactoryImpl implements ProgressWorkerFactory, ApplicationContextAware  {


    private ProgressWorker1 progressWorker1;
    private ProgressWorker2 progressWorker2;
    private static ApplicationContext CTX;


    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        CTX = ctx;
    }


    @Override
    public ProgressWorker getProgressWorker(int type) {
        switch(type) {
            case 1:
                progressWorker1 = (ProgressWorker1) CTX.getBean("progressWorker1");
                return progressWorker1;
            case 2:
                progressWorker2 = (ProgressWorker2) CTX.getBean("progressWorker2");
                return progressWorker2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to these beans anywhere else?

Comment: No, I've searched through my context xml files and also checked by commenting out the progressWorker1, progressWorker2 beans from my applicationContext.xml file and the application starts up without error.  The ProgressWorkerFactory bean is a property of one other bean, a ProgressService bean.  It's the ProgressService bean which calls the ProgressWorkerFactory.getProgressWorker() method.  These are also new beans and pieces of code I've added to the application this morning.

Comment: It works fine for me. You must have another reference to the beans that is forcing them to be initialized

Comment: You're right.  I have created a simple web project (my project is a Spring MVC project) and it works.  I've gone back to my project and doesn't work.  What I also have in my project is DWR (the project is a few years old now).  If I comment out the DWR configuration from my web.xml file, the lazy loading works.  I'll edit my original question.

Comment: I don't see how the DWR servlet would be involved. Does it take anything from your Spring `ApplicationContext`?

Comment: Hi @Sotirios, I found the problem was with having two servlets defined in the web.xml.  I found the examples on these pages provided me with the correct web.xml and DWR configuration. **www.butterdev.com** [link](http://www.butterdev.com/dwr/2008/02/dwr-and-spring-a-configuration-for-everyone/)